# Standalone vCenter web client

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I wish to have a VMWare vCenter Web Client without setting up vCenter Server Systems such that the Web Client connects directly to an ESXi host.

I only have 1 ESXi host, setting up vCenter seems unnecessary, I just want to be able to access via the web.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible. If you wish to use the current vCenter Web Access, you'll need to install the full vCenter package.

Answer (score 0):

vmware labs has released a tool called [esxi embedded host client](https://labs.vmware.com/flings/esxi-embedded-host-client) that enables a light web client with some basic features:

- VM operations (Power on, off, reset, suspend, etc).
- Creating a new VM, from scratch or from OVF/OVA (limited OVA support)
- Configuring NTP on a host
- Displaying summaries, events, tasks and notifications/alerts
- Providing a console to VMs
- Configuring host networking
- Configuring host advanced settings
- Configuring host services